# If we declare an array of four elements, can these elements store values?

Tags: c++, c

In C++ if we declare an array of four elements, can these elements store values? I mean, if we declare the following array:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int a[4];
    double res;
    double avg;
    avg = res = 0.0; 
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Please enter age ";
        cin>> a[i];
    }

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        cout<< "You have entered these ages " <<a[i];
        cout<<endl;
        res += a[i];
    }

    avg = res/4;
    cout<< "Total is "<<res <<endl;
    cout<< "Avg is "<<avg;
}
```

this above program is a program with an integer (numeric) array, while in character array can we assign any value of the character array's elements?

Comment: Whys this tagged as PHP?

Comment: You declare an array of three integers, and access elements two (`a[1]`) to five (`a[4]`) of that array.

Comment: Arrays in C are 0-indexed, so your loops should be `for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)`, otherwise you are attempting to read past the end of the array (which is not allowed).

Comment: it was by mistake bro !!!!

Comment: tell me can i assign any value to character array elements ??

Comment: What would be the purpose of arrays if it could not store values? O_o

Comment: @dreamlax yes i would to do next time better as you said

Comment: i am just asking about the character array ??? i am li'll confused about that, in that array char name[5] = {'j','a','c','o','b'}; can we assign any value to the elements j,a,c,o and b ???/

Comment: @Muhammad Sohaib Afzaal yes. data type char is of size 1 byte. any value of size 1 byte can be assigned to each index of a char array

Comment: @Muhammad Sohaib Afzaal. In which array? char name[5] can store five characters. in your comment you have intailaise name[0] to j name[1] to a .. name[4] to b. you can assign any such values to each index of name char array

Comment: There is so much wrong with this code I don't even know where to begin.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Array is a placeholder for the values of same type and no. of places are reserved during array declarion.

```
int a[3];
```

means it can store 3 ints. to be accessed as `a[0]`, `a[1]` and `a[2]`.

Now, you can see the problem you have in your loop:

```
for(int i=1; i<=4; i++)
{
    cout<<"Please enter age ";
    cin>> a[i];
}
```

1. `a[0]` remains empty
2. loop runs 4 times: `a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]` and, last 2 indices are not reserved.

You can correct it as following:

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    cout<<"Please enter age ";
    cin>> a[i];
}
```

your other question:

> while in character array can we assign any value of the character array's elements

Nope, Each index will store exactly one `char`.

```
char c[3];
```

will store exactly 3 `char`s. if you tried to use other indices it may result into undefined behaviour, segmentation fault. as you are trying to access memory that was not allocated to your process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the declared elements are available to store values.

However, in your example you have only declared a 3-element array, which gives you array elements `a[0], a[1],` and `a[2]`. You are accessing array elements `a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]`, resulting in an out-of-bounds situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether it's possible to assign a value to an element of an array, then the answer is yes. All of the following is perfectly valid:

```
char a[10];
a[4] = 'x';
std::cin >> a[6];
```

Note however that your code contains errors:

1. You index `a` with indices 1 to 4. This means `a` must be at least 5 elements long; it's currently defined with length of 3.
2. `#include <iostream.h>` should be just `#include <iostream>`. `<iostream.h>` is pre-standard and obsolete.
3. C++ array indices are 0 based, so while not technically an error, you're ignoring the first element of your array. You should probably phrase your `for` loops as `for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)`